# p2.js body position is NaN when spawned inside of each other

Tags: javascript, physics-engine

I'm working on a project for which I need a physics engine. At the moment I'm playing around with p2.js but I'm running into a problem:

When I try to create multiple bodies (circles and/or boxes) which overlap the positions are set to NaN as soon as world.step() is called. The bodies have a mass of 5 and are dynamic.

In very rare occasions it does actually work. How can I make sure it works every time? Do I have to wait for the bodies to be initialized?

4 circles before the simulation starts, once world.step is called the positions of these circles is NaN:
[image]

```
var world = new p2.World({
    gravity: [0, 9.82]
});
function PhysicsBody(type, x, y, widthOrRadius, height) {
    this.body = new p2.Body({
        mass: 5,
        position: [x, y],
    });
    this.type = type;
    if (this.type == 'rectangle') {
        this.shape = new p2.Box({ width: widthOrRadius, height: height });
    }
    else if (this.type == 'circle') {
        this.shape = new p2.Circle({ radius: widthOrRadius });
    }
    this.body.addShape(this.shape);
    world.addBody(this.body);
}
var bod1 = new PhysicsBody('circle', 0, 0, 32);
var bod2 = new PhysicsBody('circle', 10, 0, 32);
```

Comment: Can you post your world and body initialization codes please?

Comment: @AhmetZambak I've added a sample code.

Comment: No Idea.. I see no mistake. Try to set the position of the circle again after the initialization. Like: ''body.position.set(..)'' or maybe you have to set the postion of the "PhysicsBody" objects ?? OR use external variables for positions.

Comment: Setting the body position after initialization doesn't work. The position will then become NaN again as soon as step() is called. I'm starting to think that this is an issue with the library. I've created an issue on github but the project doesn't seem to have been updated in the last 4 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seem to run fine. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5dthnaw/

How do you call world.step() ? Perhaps some strange value got passed to it. You can call it in the following ways:

1. `world.step(dt)` where dt is the number of seconds for a tick, for example `1/60`.
2. `world.step(dt, elapsedTime, maxSubSteps);`, for example `world.step(1/60, 1/60, 10);`

All numbers you pass to step() must be nonzero.

Comment: Oops, dt was zero the first time step() was called because of the way I'm getting a deltaTime.